# Is there any known php libraries that mark changes in text like Quora does in their notifications feed? If not what algorithmn shall I use?

Tags: php, algorithm, text

I'm trying to implement a notification system like Quoras, where changes is marked with red and green. Red for old text and green for new. If you have a Quora account go to http://www.quora.com/notifications and you will know what I mean or just look at the example below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diff, match, patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) is a good starting point. The [downloadable zip](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/downloads/detail?name=diff_match_patch_20110603.zip&can=2&q=) has implementations for C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Lua, ObjC and Python. PHP is not on the list, but you could presumably well use the JavaScript version, or port it yourself to PHP (with implementations in 7 languages, it's probably feasible).

Comment: thanks for the fast respones! It looks like this is what I need

Comment: someone has been working on a PHP but not recently https://github.com/nuxodin/diff_match_patch-php